# Are mutant powers hereditary?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

According to "X-Men Origins: Wolverine" Wolverine and his half brother victor share the same healing powers, or pretty close to the same powers.  I read somewhere on this site that Logan also has a son that has healing powers.

With that in mind are mutant powers hereditary?  And what happens if two mutants were to have a child? Could you breed a mutant with specific powers?

Comment: From the real world: a 'mutant' is a creature whose DNA has been modified (usually in far less interesting ways than X-men). By definition DNA is inherited, so mutations are always inherited, though the child gets a 50% chance of getting the mutated gene from one parent or the non-mutated from the other. We now return you to regular programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes!

It makes intuitive sense that, if a mutant were to reproduce, the offspring would have the same (or similar) powers.  Right off the top of my head, I can think of a few examples from the comics:

-Daken, Wolverine's son, who has basically the same powers

-Beak and Angel have kids who appear to be a weird mishmash of their powers

-Rachel Summers has an array of psionic powers inherited from her mother, alternate-universe Jean Grey

So there's a lot of evidence that, at least to some degree, mutant powers are hereditary.  I don't know much about breeding a mutant with specific powers, but I'd suggest looking into some Mr. Sinister stories if you want to find out more about that.

Comment: Also Nightcrawler / Azazel...

Comment: @AviD: But that would require me to admit Austen's run happened.  Which costs us Claremont's single best stealth relationship/gag.  Absolutely not.  By way of compensation, I'll suggest: Cable / Nathan Summers (who in all versions has his mother's telekinetic abilities), Siryn (Banshee's scream), and in the Ultimates universe, David Xavier.

Comment: Professor Xavier's son David Haller (Legion).
Emma Frost's in vitro offspring, the Stepford Cuckoos.